# Adding matrices manually and in for loop gives different results

Tags: matlab

I have few images in a structure which i want to add and binarize in order to get some common area. Problem is when I am adding them like:

```
summed_matrix1 = stack(1).raw + stack(2).raw + stack(3).raw + stack(4).raw + stack(5).raw
```

and when am adding them through following for loop:

```
[row,col]=size(stack(1).raw);
summed_matrix2=zeros(row,col);
for i=1:5
  summed_matrix2=summed_matrix2+stack(i).raw;
end
```

then final output in both cases is different. What am i missing here? should they not be same?

here is the output of `imshowpair(summed_matrix1,summed_matrix2)`(if it helps!)[image: output of imshowpair, showing the differnce]

Comment: Are you sure you aren't altering `stack` in between the two calcs? Do you run them one after the other immediately with no other code in between?

Comment: no. and to make things more interesting. if i run command `summed_matrix2=summed_matrix2+stack(1).raw` manually, multiple time with different stack().raw (i.e without for loop, running it with stack(1), stack(2) etc), output matches with simple addition!!

Comment: I think without a minimal executable example we can't help you properly.

Comment: Shall I upload images and script somewhere? And just FYI, matlab version is 2013b

Comment: Running the above command with randomized data in `stack` produces the same result for both ways of calculating `summed_matrix`. Could you edit your answer to include a **reproducible** minimal example?

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I restarted matlab to write some executable and now its all behaving properly. I really have no clue as to what went wrong. If any suggestions and ideas are there on what it was, it will be good, else close down the question?

Comment: probably your output matrices already had some value, you can `clear` them before.

Comment: I dont know. I explicitly checked again and again, ran it several time, clearing and initializing every variable carefully just to avoid making a fool of myself here! and yet ended up doing precisely that!

Comment: Are you sure your stacks are two-dimensional? And not maybe X-Y-RGB?

Comment: Yup. Gray scale. with `double` data type (from `im2double`). Now as i stated earlier for some weird reason all is working fine. :(